# How to run Gmail APIs on a website for multiple users?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am currently using Gmail API to develop an application to read emails for specific information that the user gives me permission for. I am able to run it for my own inbox using the [quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/quickstarts-overview).

However, I am getting confused about how to run my application on a server, so that it keeps on taking user permission and running the application for each user monthly without any input.

Any leads in the right direction would be useful.

Comment: Have you considered service account if those multiple users belong to the same domain? Check [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python_1) out.

Comment: The Users can be anyone who wishes to use the website publicly, not limited to a certain domain. Would service account work then also?

Comment: Then you might need every user to authenticate at least once if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Service accounts only work with Workspace domain accounts it will not work with normal gmail accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using this code [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Then you need to have a look at a few things about this code.

This code is designed as an installed application.

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

Which is why it says  `To learn how to create credentials for a desktop application,`  This code is designed to run on the users machine.  That is because it opens the consent screen in the browser of the machine its running on.  If you tried to put it on a server it will not work as the user wont be able to access the consent screen if it tries to open on a server.

The second issue with this code is it is designed to be single user.  When a user runs this code their consent is stored in the form of an access token and a refresh token in this file

```
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
```

So every time it runs its either going to run as the same user or you will need to remove the token.json and it will let you login as a different user.  For this to work multi user you would need to set it up to create a new json file for each user rather than single user.

You need to figure out how to get the google api python client library to run on a server for multi user i have unfortunately never figured out if it even supports that.

## verification

Are you aware of the cost of verification of an app using Gmail scopes?